# node.js serialport, trying to write and I just can't figure it out

Tags: node.js, node-serialport

My knowledge of rs232 is pretty much nothing.  I have an LED display connected to a serial port.  I'm using node.js v8.22 and node-serialport v1.1.0.

The LED display's user guide is asking for [hex80]xxxxxx[cr] to be sent, where each "x" is a single digit (0-9).  I have the baud rate at 9600 as it dictates as well.

I'm assuming i could write

```
sp.write(0x80);
sp.write('123456\r');
```

But honestly, I just don't know how to translate [hex80]xxxxxx[cr] to javascript/serialport needs.  I've tried various things.

sp.write([0x80,55,55,55,49,49,48,'\r']); // hex80 + all the char codes for the digits
sp.write(128+'123456\r') // 128 is decimal for 0x80

I have gotten some jumbled stuff to be displayed.  Full code below.

```
var serialPort, sp;

var comPort = '/dev/cu.usbserial';

var serialPort = require('serialport').SerialPort
sp = new serialPort(comPort, { baudrate: 9600, parser: parserJaCircuitsChrono() });

sp.on("open", function () {
    console.log(comPort + ' is open');
    sp.write(0x80);
    sp.write('123456\r');
});
```

Any thoughts or help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out.  I put a serial port monitoring application on to see what was happening.

The final answer was

A. When using an array or buffer to pass to the `.write()` method, it needs to be either a decimal character code (ie. 30 for "0" or 13 for carriage return) or a hex code (ie. `0x30` for "0" or `0x0D` for carriage return) for each item in the array. I didn't try unicode or anything else.  But see below my thoughts on that.

B. It turns out that in my example code

```
sp.on("open", function () {
    console.log(comPort + ' is open');
    sp.write(0x80);
    sp.write('123456\r');
});
```

I needed to be sending the 0x80 as a buffer/array instead. so `sp.write([0x80]);`, without it sent lots of 00 00 00...s   However the LED display vendor's documentation was incorrect as it needed a `\r\n` at the end and not just a `\r`.

C. (a bit of a "duh" moment) was simply that Javascript will attempt to convert anything concatenated with a string to a string.  So concatenating `0x80 + '123456\r'` turns into `'128123456\r'`.

D. Passing unicode, like `sp.write('\u0080')` ends up outputing double characters, I'm assuming since unicode is 2 bytes per character, and the string is being treated/expecting single byte encoding.  [Javascript strings are UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141136/default-javascript-character-encoding), so I'm guessing the node serialport module doesn't handle it since RS-232 uses 8 bits or less per character which falls into the typical ASCII char set.

Comment: Which serial port monitoring tool you used?

Answer (score 0):

I tested this on a console, not over a serial port, but I think it should work for you.

There are two options:  1) you can escape into Unicode or 2) you can use the String.fromCharCode function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

Escaping into Unicode is pretty simple, just use \uXXXX where XXXX is the hex representation of your number

```
sp.write('\u0080123456\r');
```

Or you can use String.fromCharCode:

```
sp.write(String.fromCharCode(128) + '123456\r');
```