# Number of chars taken by a multi byte char is different in JavaScript and MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, unicode, encoding

Recently, I came across a weird behaviour while testing a backend system which uses MySQL.

In my frontend, when I printed the length of a string, I got a different value than from the MySQL.

For the test, I'm using this `0123456789`,  and `‍♀️` emojis to check the length of the string.

**Javascript(In the browser console):**

```
> "‍♀️".length
<- 7
> "".length
<- 2
> "0123456789".length
<- 10
```

[image]

**MySQL(Using MySQL Workbench):**

```
CREATE TABLE testing_char_length 
  ( 
     id  INT auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, 
     txt VARCHAR(10) 
  ) 
DEFAULT charset utf8mb4; 

INSERT INTO testing_char_length 
            (txt) 
VALUES     ('0123456789'), 
            (''), 
            ('‍♀️'); 

SELECT *, 
       Char_length(txt) NumberOfChars, 
       Length(txt)      SizeInBytes 
FROM   testing_char_length; 

DROP TABLE testing_char_length;
```

**Output:**

```
| id    | txt           | NumberOfChars     | SizeInBytes   |
|----   |------------   |---------------    |-------------  |
| 1     | 0123456789    | 10                | 10            |
| 2     |             | 1                 | 4             |
| 3     | ‍♀️            | 5                 | 17            |
```

[image]

---

Initially I thought it might be due to some encoding issues. So, tried to search about the encodings used by Javascript and MySQL.

[Javascript uses UTF-16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11141331/4859791)

So, I also tried setting the MySQL encoding to `utf16` to be sure it is not the culprit and even after using `default charset utf16`, the output is same like in `utf8mb4`.

Why is there a difference in the number of characters in Javascript and MySQL?

I'm sure there is something which I haven't come across till now and hoping for some answers for this behaviour.

**Tested on:**

Google Chrome Version 81.0.4044.122 (Official Build) (64-bit)

MySQL Workbench: 8.0.19

MySQL: 8.0.19

OS: macOS Catalina version 10.15.3

---

**Update: 1**

The HEX codes of string `"0123456789"` are same in both JS and MySQL. Other two are not same.

[JS Fiddle for Hex values](https://jsfiddle.net/g3cex120/1/). Code to calculate HEX is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26375459/4859791)

[image: JS Hex values]

[MySQL Fiddle for Hex values](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=328a5dc9abda9d70f38f63a31c724494) (Taken from the comment [below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61808621/number-of-chars-taken-by-a-multi-byte-char-is-different-in-javascript-and-mysql/61808920?noredirect=1#comment109326705_61808621))

[image: MySQL Hex values]

Even though the encoding is same, why are the HEX values are different? Isn't UTF encoding supposed to be universal and same?

Comment: Interesting. [mysql fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=328a5dc9abda9d70f38f63a31c724494) of this. bytes was always going to be implementation dependent, but I was hoping chars would be universal. Can you get a hex encoding in javascript of these characters?

Comment: @danblack I have updated the answer with the Hex encodings in js.

Comment: I just tested your fiddle.  has extra characters next to it in the fiddle that are not in your database.

Comment: [JS Fiddle for Hex values](https://jsfiddle.net/g3cex120/1/) is not correct.

Comment: @StackSlave I just checked. I think it’s  a bug in the JS fiddle editor. It is showing like it has a space after the emoji but when I try to delete it, the emoji is being deleted. And also in the alert, it is showing fine. I have also copied the emoji from the JS fiddle along with the quotes to test whether it has a space or not and there was no space when I pasted that into the chrome console and some other text fields to double check.

Comment: Great. Glad you figured it out!

Comment: @StackSlave No. The problem is still there. I was just giving an explanation for your comment about inputs being different. The hex values are still not same even though the emojis are same.

Answer (score 0):

As you found out, your app language is using UTF-16, while MySQL is using its utf8mb4 (aka UTF-8).

UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32 have different hex representations, potentially a different number of bytes and "characters", but can be transformed from one to another.

In the "BMP", 16-bit characters can be represented in 3 bytes in utf8 or 2 bytes in utf16.  Beyond that, utf8 goes to 4 bytes (1 character) and utf16 goes to 4 bytes (2 characters).  That 2nd character is saying "panic, we exceeded 16 bits, we need something to extend the character set".

Potentially, utf8 could go to 5 bytes, but no such characters have been standardized on.